# “he was nobody” VS "he was a nobody"

Tags: word-usage, articles, zero-article

Nobody, as a countable noun, can mean "*a very unimportant person*" as in:

> *A man in my position has nothing to fear from a nobody like you.*

But I don't quite sure about this example from [the free dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nobody):

> *I knew him when he was nobody*.

Is it also correct to say *I knew him when he was **a** nobody*? Any reason behind this?

How about ***He is nobody*** VS ***He is a nobody***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To be nobody** is to lack reputation and its prerogatives.

**To be a nobody** is to be one of the multitude of nobodies who lack reputation and its prerogatives.